# Не могу понять, можно для элементы p установить отрицательный отступ

Tags: html, css

У меня возник вопрос, в данный момент я верстаю PSD-макет, и в нем есть параграфы (p), и они расположены снизу, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы они были чуть сверху...

И у меня вопрос, я смогу для элемента p задать отрицательный margin-top, ну чтобы элементы p были чуть сверху?

Comment: а почему бы не попробовать задать и посмотреть результат?

Comment: минусовой `margin - есть`, а вот `padding - нет`

Answer (score 0):

Можно, почему нет, но может стоит просто у предыдущего элемента сделать меньше отступ...

Пример:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(255,100,10);
}
p {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 255, 100);
}
```

```html
 <div></div>
 <p>Text</p>
```

[пример Codepen](https://codepen.io/MaxManchak/pen/QxxEaz)

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался!

Просто мне нужно было задать свойство position...

Answer (score 0):

Бро чтобы задать отрицательные поля/отступы застайль этот элемент с параметрами position:realative; а потом двигай в отрицательные числа типа top:-100px;

```
p {
position:relative;
top:-100px;
}
```